# Inline editing not working for some users

Tags: inline, user-interface

EDITED:

After further tests, Inline editing isn't working for this user for any object. Although, the User Interface looks ok (actually - ALL CB's - but last three - are checked)

Weird!!

Inline editing is enabled:

[image]

UPDATE: It's not working in any view.

But on Custom Object - nothing

Suggested solution in SF site - My edit button is not overridden : http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004555&language=en_US

[image]

I have tested with my user name: it works. than logged with the effected user on my machine: inline isn't working.

Edit option is available for that user, for that object.

[image]

EDIT

I found another differance between the user's account and mine.

The top bar, on my account, is a drop down

[image]

While on the user's account, it's not

[image]

Although, the setting, which I think effects this, was reset in both, the user's account, and mine (to try and solve it)

[image]

Comment: Are you using record types for that object? Are fields that you wish to edit editable in the field level security or in page layout?

Comment: I don't use record types. If using the edit button, same field is editable.

Comment: Do you mean that you have overriden a standard page layout with a visualforce page with an inline support inside? If so, what component you use: apex:detail or apex:pageBlock structure?

Comment: @mast0r nothing of that kind. standard page layout

Comment: What field type? Is inline editing not working for that user for all field types?

Comment: Simple text field, inline editing isn't working at all for this user. Also tested on my machine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

check if accessibility mode is enabled for these users. I have faced so many challenges because of accessibilty mode.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=accessibility_enabling.htm&language=en_US

If you go to a user detail section you should be able to see accessibility mode enabled for them and it clearly states some js functions might not work when enabled.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with the Accounts object inline editing not working. The help bubbles weren't working either for some users. Turns out on the users that it wasn't working in the Page Layout the Quick Action Log A Call was being used in the Publisher Quick Actions. I removed it and it fixed the issue. So if you are having a similar issue I would suggest looking through the quick actions in the page and removing some of them to see if it fixes the issue. Seems that some of the Quick Actions only work for some objects.

Answer (score 1):

Advanced List Views and in-line editing are available for pretty much every object except Users.  The idea is being reviewed by Salesforce.  Please vote for it. https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqoNAAS

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to inline edit in a list view? If so then the records displayed should of same record type, It will work if you make Record Type on the the criteria on the List View.

Comment: Neither list view works, nor other. I don't user record types, don't see reason to add that to the filter